# Is it possible to build an OpenCV app on Linux and execute it on Windows?

Tags: python, linux, windows, opencv, deep-learning

I am new on Linux, OpenCV and deep learning, in fact I just started with these things a couple weeks ago.

In my reserches I found a lot of people saying that is much better use OpenCV on Linux than on Windows, so, that is what I am doing. I installed an Ubuntu distro on a VM and I am using it to study.

But today a doubt came up into my mind. It would be possible to write an OpenCV app on Linux and use it on Windows? I've read a lot and I couldn't find a satisfatory answer.

Maybe this is a silly question, but as I said, I am very new on all of that stuff.

For now, I am just studying and I am really feeling like learning Linux, but when I'll really start to build my applications it will be important to being able to run them on Windows.

So, if this is possible, is there some specific things that I should do to make the trasition easier?

Comment: If you are just learning, you can stick to Linux. If you really want to run it on windows, the same executable that is, you can use WSL. It is not clear in the question why you need windows.

Comment: @Ganesh Kathiresan I see. Thank you for answering. I am concerned about Windows for two reasons, one is I'll need to use some windows software to support the development of a couple ideas I have, these ideas are the reasons I am learning OpenCV and deep learning (not Linux, this is an old desire), at least at first, besides that I was thinking about projects that I could build and open to the ordinary public, as we know, most people use Windows, so it would be very frustating to create something and not be able to deliver to the target audience just for being in the wrong OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference in the syntaxes of opencv between different operating systems. (Well, I used both and didn't bother me.) So it should be fine as long as you have the same version of Opencv installed as there are differences between opencv 3x and opencv 4x.